# How to solve error: “cannot find symbol class R”

Tags: android, build, dialogflow-es

I've downloaded a project from GitHub, and am trying to run it. I downloaded it from https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client.git.

When I open it and gradle synced, it worked fine. But when I try to build the project, I am getting an error, "error: cannot find symbol class R".

But when I got to the declaration of R, the class file is created. I tried my options like, removing R from the import section, cleaned, rebuilt, invalidated caches, etc. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: This is what I did: git clone the repo, build the project, build/clean/rebuild project; got your same errors. Did File/Close Project, reopen it and Run apiAISampleApp: it worked

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried many times..but not solved my issue... I tried in my two machines.. in both I am getting same error

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio) you can try:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart.
```

Quote from above link:

> Whenever you see this error after moving Java files or directories to other locations, then you can guarantee that Android Studio has gotten confused.

From [this other link](https://firstandgeek.com/solved-cannot-resolve-symbol-r/), it states that you might want to clean and rebuild the project a few times:

> Didn’t work on your first try? Repeating the procedure a few times may provide positive results. Remember, to perform the above operation in quick succession

Also, make sure that all your resources have different names:

> There are instances where a developer may fail to name a resource correctly or one may opt to name multiple resources with the same name. If some of your resources contain the same name or they have invalid characters, then the error will occur and affect your project.

I’ve experienced this error before, as well, and after trying the different solutions shown in the links, it should eventually fix itself.

Comment: thanks. I tried all the solutions in the link. I tried in my mac and windows machines, still getting same error. still trying to resolve.

Comment: That's tough. Are you getting any other errors along with the "cannot find symbol class R"?

Comment: Also, did you update the info in the AndroidManifest? @user867662

Comment: there is no issue with AndroidManifest. There is no other errors. But the wonderful thing is even the Build > Rebuild Project is showing compilation error, when I connect phone and run the app into phone, it worked, the apk installed into device and its working fine. But still the Build > Rebuild Project  is failing :(

Comment: @user867662 So, the app runs fine and the only thing you can't do at the moment is rebuild your project, right? If the error is still "Cannot resolve symbol R", you could try deleting the R file. The project will then generate a new one.